# Multitenancy (Acts as Tenant gem): How to delete a tenant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, multi-tenant, acts-as-tenant

I am using the [Acts as Tenant gem for Rails](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) and, if I understood it right when using the `acts_as_tenant :tenant` on `models/course.rb`, it automatically includes the relationships between models (i.e. `belongs_to :tenant` and `has_many :courses`).

So, now I am trying to delete a tenant and I get the error below:

```
[3e5da695-5075-4901-b013-dd2d1f7afcda] app/controllers/super_admin/tenants_controller.rb:54:in `destroy'
2022-03-18T20:25:53.000000+00:00 app[postgres.3099747]: [DATABASE] [13-1]  sql_error_code = 23503 ERROR:  update or delete on table "tenants" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_ff24ac10ab" on table "courses"
2022-03-18T20:25:53.000000+00:00 app[postgres.3099747]: [DATABASE] [13-2]  sql_error_code = 23503 DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1177) is still referenced from table "courses".
2022-03-18T20:25:53.000000+00:00 app[postgres.3099747]: [DATABASE] [13-3]  sql_error_code = 23503 STATEMENT:  DELETE FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."id" = $1
```

And I get a 500 error. Should I add all the `has_many` relationships to the Tenant model and include `dependent: :destroy`? (I want to delete those objects as well)